# OData is really hypermedia-driven?

Tags: rest, odata

I've seen over there that OData provides hypermedia-driven support.

However I've not been able to figure out how or why OData provides this support.

1. Which hypermedia links does OData provide?
2. Does it mean that I'm able to build a client using whichever hypermedia links?

How could I use both a REST-based API and a OData service?

Comment: Default OData does not offer much hypermedia link support, there are however libraries which can help you implement it. - "How could I use both a REST-based API and a OData service?" What do you mean with that? An OData serice *is* a REST API (Generally speaking..., when implemented properly etc.)

Comment: Could you provide me which libraries are you commenting me that would help me to implement hypermedia link support?

Comment: You might want to have a look at this: [NHateoas](https://github.com/yury-sannikov/NHateoas). I though it was an OData library, however it's just a general WebAPI lib so I'm not sure if it'll work for you :/